# How to call public method from a event handler

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dom-events

I have the function below.
Everything works fine except for the `Push`, `Pop` and `Remove` method. These method should be called by the event-handler. This event is fired by the Google Maps API.

The problem is that when the event is fired, these method are not found. I have a "**Push is not defined**" error message.

I tried with **this** but that's not working.

How do I call the public method from the event handler?

```
function Track(mapContainer) {
var map = mapContainer;
var points = new Array();

var isEditMode = false;

var clickListener;

this.Push = function(point) { ... }

this.Pop = function() { ... }

this.Remove = function(point) { ... }

//Enable / disable the marker placements
this.PlaceWaypoint = function(isPlacing) {
    if (isPlacing != true) {
        if (clickListener != null) {
            google.maps.event.removeListener(clickListener);
            clickListener = null;
        }
    } else {
        clickListener = map.AddEvent("click", function(event) {
            if (!IsDoubleClick()) {
                var point = map.PlaceMarker(new WayPoint(event.latLng))
                point.RemoveListener(function() { Remove(point); });
                Push(point);
            } else {
                Pop();
            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a closure/binding problem. One convention that is frequently used it to assign a variable called **self** of **that**, which can later be used in place of **this**, thanks to the closure properties of JS.

```
function Track(mapContainer) {
   var map = mapContainer,
       points = new Array(),
       isEditMode = false,
       clickListener,
       // Make a variable self that points to this, that can be used inside closures
       // where the original context is lost
       self = this;

   this.Push = function(point) { ... }

   this.Pop = function() { ... }

   this.Remove = function(point) { ... }

   //Enable / disable the marker placements
   this.PlaceWaypoint = 
       function(isPlacing) {
            if (isPlacing != true) {
                if (clickListener != null) {
                    google.maps.event.removeListener(clickListener);
                    clickListener = null;
                }
            } else {
                clickListener = map.AddEvent("click", function(event) {
                    if (!IsDoubleClick()) {
                        var point = map.PlaceMarker(new WayPoint(event.latLng))
                        point.RemoveListener(function() { Remove(point); });
                        // Use the closure reference self instead of this
                        self.Push(point);
                    } else {
                        // Use the closure reference self instead of this
                        self.Pop();
                    }
                });
        };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all Pop and Push is not global, second this in the inner scope has another meaning. So you can use closure and rename the "**this**" to variable of more global scope.

```
function Track(mapContainer) {

//....
var $this = this;

//Enable / disable the marker placements
this.PlaceWaypoint = function(isPlacing) {
    if (isPlacing != true) {
        if (clickListener != null) {
            google.maps.event.removeListener(clickListener);
            clickListener = null;
        }
    } else {
        clickListener = map.AddEvent("click", function(event) {
            if (!IsDoubleClick()) {
                var point = map.PlaceMarker(new WayPoint(event.latLng))
                point.RemoveListener(function() { $this.Remove(point); });
                $this.Push(point);
            } else {
                $this.Pop();
            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

Comment: it's probably better to scope this to the function by adding var in front of it, otherwise if we have multiple instances of Track, the $this-variable will be overwritten and methods invoked on the wrong instance.

Comment: @Machine, thank got pointing to mistake, have fixed it accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

`this` always refers to the context of the current function, so if you use `this` in your event handler it refers to that function calls `this`, not the `this` in your `Track` function.

To create a closure that accesses the `this` of an outer scope, you need to assign that `this` to a new variable which can be accessed from the inner function:

```
var self = this;
this.PlaceWaypoint = function(isPlacing) {
   // ...
   self.Pop();
   // ...
}
```